# Anonymous type broken after linq select

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I've got a strange problem with an anonymous type. Lets jump right into my code:

```
var anon = new[] 
{
    new { Var1 = 20, Var2 = 40, Var3 = 70 },
    new { Var1 = 25, Var2 = 45, Var3 = 75 }
};

// found should be of type { int Var1, int Var2, int Var3 }
var found = anon.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Var1 == 25);

var test = found.Var1 // <-- not defined error here
```

**Quite easy question:**
Why cant I access `Var1` after using a linq select?

*Sorry for this topic, couldnt think of a better description for this.*

Comment: in this situation compiler must generate an error message which explain why `Var1` is not available

Comment: Stupid mistake I've made. Cant even delete because there are answers already.

Comment: found.FirstorDefault().Var1 should get you the 1st element from anon list.

Comment: FYI. `Select(x => x)` is not needed here (or really ever).

Comment: I've voted for closing aswell. Was just brain-afk.

Comment: @juharr Thanks for that info. Havnt known I could do it without the `Select()` part. At least one thing this question was good for.

Comment: Short version: `var found = anon.First(x => x.Var1 == 25);`

Comment: @C4ud3x The only time you need it is if you actually project the query to something different `Select(x => x.Something)` or if you are using query syntax `from x in stuff where x.Y = 1 select x;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) returns you [`IEnumerable<>`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwiqq6znx4TNAhWJDsAKHZT6C14QFggzMAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.collections.ienumerable(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHAfEuGK6fhIP3dMWzul_HMmAz23g&bvm=bv.123325700,d.ZGg&cad=rja), not a single element. 
You can use `First` or `FirstOrDefault` to get first element.

```
found.First().Var1
```

Comment: Oh lol im stupid. Sure, multiple results possible. >.<. Im sorry.

Answer (score 2):

[`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) returns an [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) and is used for 0-n results.

If you'll always have 1 result you want [`Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you'll have 0-1 results you want [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you'll have 1-n results you want [`First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you'll have 0-n results you want [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Valentin was first I guess. I anyway upvoted this for providing the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C# compiler on this machine, but probably its because found is an Iterable of the anonymus type. Try use `anon.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Var1 == 25).First()` or `anon.Select(x => x).Where(x => x.Var1 == 25).FirstOrDefault()`. Also, i am pretty sure you dont need the select, you could just use `anon.Where(x => x.Var1 == 25).First()`